# Check before proceeding if the task in BackgroundWorker has completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, winforms

I have a Login Form (which has a label that will show status of background process, username and password text boxes, Login and Cancel buttons) along with that I have a background worker to do some time taking task (in the meanwhile when Login Form loads and user provide details in text boxes).

Background task keep running while the user will be providing username and password on Login Form. As soon as the user hits the Login button I want to check the status if the background process has completed successfully and then only it should proceed (launch the MainForm)

Otherwise should pop-up error. Following is what I did to achieve but the 'while()' strategy doesn't look elegant. Is there any more appropriate way?

```
  public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        private static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        enum status
        {
            Blank,
            Success,
            Error
        };

        public LoginForm()
        {
            InterimProceedings();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InterimProceedings()
        {

            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += 
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

            if (!bw.IsBusy)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("BackgroundWorker is busy");
            }
        }

        private static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
          //  Time taking task
              mre.Set();
        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                this.lbl_status.Text = "Cannot proceed, Error occured";
                appStatus = status.Error;
            }
            else
            {
                this.lbl_status.Text = "Good to go...";
                appStatus = status.Success;
            }
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mre.WaitOne();

            if(appStatus == status.Success)
            {
                // Proceed with intended work
            }

            else
            {
                // Pop-up error occurred
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just replace the while loop with a call to show the error?

Comment: What are you processing in the background all the time while the login screen is being shown?

Comment: Session Factory is being built and querying DB in background

Comment: You should disable the button and show a progress bar until the background work is done. "Setting up your stuff..." type message when logging in to something is acceptable.

Comment: Uhm: `if (!(e.Error == null))`? Why not use `!=`? And IMHO you should try to avoid a negative check when possible, so do `if (e.Error == null) {} else {}`. Also, doesn't this question belong on StackOverflow, since you're not really asking for a code review but really for a solution to a problem? Isn't this "broken" code, considering it doesn't do what you want it to?

Comment: @RobH Great idea. With Sadiq's current implementation, I would be very confused if there was no indication that background work was going on that would cause an error message box to show up when I'm trying to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred solution for this kind of problem is to use async-await. It might seem like black magic at first, but once you get the hang of it, it can be extremely powerful, and elegant.

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    private readonly Task _preLoginTask;

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _preLoginTask = PerformPreLoginWorkAsync();
    }

    private async Task PerformPreLoginWorkAsync()
    {
        lbl_status.Text = @"Pre login work started";

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Long running work runs on thread pool thread
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        });

        lbl_status.Text = @"Pre login work completed";
    }

    private async void btn_login_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_login.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            lbl_status.Text = @"Waiting for pre login work to complete";

            await _preLoginTask;

            // Continue with the rest of the login here

            lbl_status.Text = @"Logged in";
        }
        catch (MyKnownException recoverableException)
        {
            lbl_status.Text = recoverableException.Message;
        }
        btn_login.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) is quite good if you want to pick up the basics quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ManualResetEvent` to wait until background work is done. So, you can define in `LoginForm` as:

```
private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

When background work is completed, you should change the state of `mre` from the thread method `bw_DoWork` and update `appStatus`:

```
mre.Set();
```

`btn_login_Click` should wait for `mre` instead of `while` loop:

```
mre.WaitOne();
```

The complete code:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    private static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    enum status
    {
        Blank,
        Success,
        Error
    };

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InterimProceedings();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InterimProceedings()
    {
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

        if (!bw.IsBusy)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("BackgroundWorker is busy");
        }
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      //  Time taking task
      //  Update appStatus
      appStatus = status.Success;
      mre.Set();
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            this.lbl_status.Text = "Cannot proceed, Error occured";
            appStatus = status.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            this.lbl_status.Text = "Good to go...";
            appStatus = status.Success;
        }
    }

    private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mre.WaitOne();

        if(appStatus == status.Success)
        {
            // Proceed with intended work
        }

        else
        {
            // Pop-up error occurred
        }
    }
}
```

---

The check against `e.Error` on `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` should change for clarity:

```
if (e.Error == null)
{
    this.lbl_status.Text = "Good to go...";
}
else
{
    this.lbl_status.Text = "Cannot proceed, Error occured";
}
```

---

I can't probe this code right now... I hope it's ok.

Comment: putting appStatus = status.Success; in DoWork() seems like you are forcing it to say it was successful, even if it is not. Correct approach is to set it in bw_RunWorkerCompleted()

Comment: It's an example. Set `appStatus` to the correct value (I don't know the details of the background work).

Comment: ManualResetEvent was helpful. Thanks for that but if in DoWork() my code fails (where I'm building SessionFactory) my UI gets freeze. Doesn't even executes RunWorkerCompleted(). Why is that?

Comment: `DoWork` always should call `mre.Set();`. Also on error.

Comment: But its neither calling mre.Set(); nor  RunWorkerCompleted() in case of failure when button is clicked before RunWorkerCompleted() is executed

Comment: Fix your code controlling exceptions or solving another bugs. If you catch your exceptions, `mre.Set()` can be called even on error conditions.

Comment: If I put try catch around time taking task then even if it has failed, in  RunWorkerCompleted() e.Error use to be null. Strange!!

Comment: You can call `mre.Set()` and re-throw the exception. But I think this is a different problem than original question.

Comment: Thanks for your time, as we are now discussing on some new patterns, I have created a new Question for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823197/in-backgroundworker-runworkercompleteds-e-error-null-even-in-case-of-error

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).